# Download Starter Code results in Error 401: No user is logged in

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I have an existing Bluemix application that was originally created from the Node-RED Starter boilerplate, but I have added IoT Foundation, Mobile Security and Push to it as well. When I go to "Start Coding" and then click <kbd>Download Starter Code</kbd>, a new browser tab opens with the content

> Error 401: No user is logged in

I have logged out and back in again, cleared browser cache, tried another browser and anything else I could think of, but still get this error.
Any ideas?

Comment: just got the same error.  Maybe the system is experiencing some issues.  I got a "server down" message earlier.

Comment: Are you the Dallas or London environment?

Comment: I am in the Dallas environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue and is currently being addressed. Stay tuned.

Comment: not working.  i am getting the same issue. it's a bit disappointing when I am testing Bluemix to consider it as an option for our client.

Comment: Hmm, please try again, as I have not been able to reproduce this issue this morning.  I added all of the services as indicated and was able to download the starter code without any problems.